# Matlab MCR program errors corrupt terminal

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I have compiled a Matlab routine using the MCR and deployed it to other computers without having them installed matlab. So far, so good. But of course, the routine is not completely error-free, particularly the GUI part. The problem is that when the MCR tries to write the error message to the terminal, it seems to corrupt the terminal so that everything is no longer legible - not even the prompt. Sometimes I also get an extra window, vaguely resembling the matlab editor window, full of illegible ascii characters. Does anyone know what is causing this, or how to avoid it?

My first attempt was a big try-catch block around everything, but whatever it is still seems to get through. The catch block just tries to divert the error to an errordlg rather than the command prompt:

```
catch e
    errordlg({e.message;['in: ',e.stack.name]})
end
```

Comment: Could you share your `catch` block?

Comment: Is this compiled as a Windows Standalone program or Command Prompt program?

Comment: Do you not observe this behavior in the non-compiled version of the program?

Comment: @HebeleHododo, I've added it now. It's nothing special though.

Comment: @Bill its a linux standalone program. I'm not sure what a "Command Prompt Program" is.

Comment: @jerad no. There are still errors, but within matlab the error messages appear in the command window or an errordlg, as normal.

Comment: Error messages should not be printed to command window with this `catch` block. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Yes - the GUI is set up to call other functions from completely different m-files when buttons are pressed or context menus are opened. So these functions will never see the try/catch. There are also mex files involved which use mexPrintf and mexErrMsgTxt. Just to be clear, the catch block isn't causing the problem, it's my first attempt at solving it.

Comment: Command Prompt is the Windows version of Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB Compiler does not support command window functions.

Peter Webb tells on [Loren's blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/09/17/managing-non-deployable-functions-in-a-compiled-application/):

> Certain MATLAB functions cannot be deployed because they act on
>   objects that are not present in a deployed application. For example,
>   since deployed applications have no command window, functions that
>   modify the command window can't be deployed.

So, you probably need to get rid of any function that prints to the command window.

Also, you can check out the `mccExcludedFiles.log` file.

Comment: thanks. I think that's put me on the right track. I have found a few examples of the things Peter warns about e.g. set(gca, 'ButtonDownFcn', 'LogButtonPress'); cd(my_path); unix(my_string);
I'll go away and try and fix those now, and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: after changing as many of these as possible, the program corrupts the terminal much less frequently. There are a couple I couldn't work around `unix(['find...`, `unix(['ln -s` and some `get`/`set` operations on graphical items, and that's probably the reason for the remaining occurrences.